# Yesod logInfo no output

Tags: logging, yesod

I am not getting any output from `$logInfo` in Yesod.

I have a scaffolded site and when I run `yesod devel`, I see no output from the log lines I put in my application. I also tried building the application (with cabal) and running from the command line, but still, no output.

I was under the impression that in development mode, all log levels are output.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I built a "fresh" application using the latest version of Yesod (downloaded with cabal just now). I modified `getHomeR` in `Home.hs` as follows:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
    getHomeR = do
        $(logInfo) "Greeting from getHomeR"
        (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
        let submission = Nothing :: Maybe (FileInfo, Text)
            handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text
        defaultLayout $ do
            aDomId <- newIdent
            setTitle "Welcome To Yesod!"
            $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

I then ran `cabal install && yesod devel`. I connected to `localhost:3000` from my browser. I expected to see `Greeting from getHomeR` in the console output but it was not there.

I am running the latest Haskell platform (2013.2.0.0) installed from Homebrew on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Please provide more information in the question, like where you're adding the `$logInfo` calls. If you're able to reproduce this behavior with a plain scaffolded site, that would be good to know.

Comment: Please see my updated question above.

Comment: It *could* just be an issue of buffering. What happens if you make 50 or so requests, do you start to see any output?

Comment: Alternatively, and perhaps easier than making lots of requests, does replacing the defaultBufSize argument to newLoggerSet with 0 in Application.hs solve it?  (Buffering behaviour changed at YP1.2.5)

Comment: Duh - replace defaultBufSize with 1, not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaulRouse's answer worked. I changed the `defaultBufSize` to `1` and started getting log output.