# Yesod Logging with System-Log-FastLogger

Tags: haskell, logging, yesod

Total n00b here trying to figure out how to log in a site I've inherited from another.  My Yesod app (currently running using yesod devel on an OSX Yosemite machine) is using System-Log-Fastlogger.  I am getting a 500 error on a page I want to troubleshoot (it builds fine using Stack, so it's runtime)... so I add the line

```
$(logInfo) "Greeting from your debugger!"
```

to my handler.  Builds fine.  Doesn't log.  I know the code is being entered because I see the 500 errors in my yesod devel console.  I saw the info on SO [Yesod logInfo no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870699/yesod-loginfo-no-output) but couldn't figure out where / how to "replace defaultBufSize with 1".  Changing the line in Application.hs from

```
import           System.Log.FastLogger                (defaultBufSize, newStdoutLoggerSet)
```

to

```
import           System.Log.FastLogger                (1, newStdoutLoggerSet)
```

gives me an error on rebuild.  Also running thru the code over and over and over to fill the buffer doesn't do the trick either.  Flummoxed.  Am I :

- not correctly understanding what stdout is in this case
- not grokking how to change the buffer size
- in over my head

Would love to know what other people do for day-to-day debugging (I confess to a lot of js `alert("Got this far!");` in my workflow).  I'm not sure how to *develop* in Yesod if I don't know how to *debug*.

Thanks for any pushes in the right direction!

Joy

Comment: The change you made says “Import the functions named `1` and `newStdoutLoggerSet` from the `System.Log.FastLogger` module”. I don't think the module exposes any function called `1`.